# ActiveRecord query for a subset of objects in order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I would like to query a large database iteratively based on an origin, order, and limit for the number of objects to return from the query. The field to order based on is passed in by the client along with the ID of the last object in the previous results.

For example, assume a table of Posts. Posts have "views" (number of views), "likes" (number of likes), and "touched" (last touched) field. The client needs to fetch 20 posts at a time by passing in the order, the limit, and the origin ID (e.g. the ID of the last object in the previous fetch).

I know how to do this by loading all the posts into memory, sorting appropriately, then finding the origin ID of the post the client passed in, then returning a number of posts after this based on the limit.

I'd like to do this all in the DB so the client passes in the sort order, the ID of the last object it received, and then have the query return the next n number of objects where n is the limit.

I'm on Rails 4 with Postgres.

Thanks!

Comment: What attribute do you want to sort by? What do you mean by "last object it received" ? Are we talking about a user's post ? You should edit your question and explain your problem a bit more.

Comment: See my edits above... the client should be able to define the attribute to sort by. In my example, this would be likes, views, or touched. The basic idea is to allow the client to iterate through a large list of objects in batches defined by the limit.

Comment: Do you want a sortable table for the user to interact with ?

Comment: I did edit the text and thought I clarified the question. In the original post, I didn't make it clear that the server should be able to return objects based on ordering either likes, views, or touched. I apologize if it's not clear still.

Comment: To make this more concrete, the client is an iOS app that allows the user to scroll through a large list of posts. The user can choose to see posts based on most recent posts, most liked posts, and most viewed. The database is very large, so the client asks for only 20 posts at at time. I was hoping to use the ID of the last post the client received to provide the server with the information it needed to fetch the next 20 based on the sort order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm obviously new to activerecord (and SQL) given how simple the answer is: In my case, using offset and limit did the trick:

Post.select("id").limit('20').offset('0').order('views DESC')

This return 20 results from offset zero ordered by views. The client would then increment the offset by the appropriate count and do the next query:

Post.select("id").limit('20').offset('20').order('views DESC')

Comment: You can do `.limit(20).offset(20)`, no need to use strings for the numbers.